# How to create Shopify app that provides custom fields (inputs) on product detail pages?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

I am trying to create a Shopify app, one which would display some extra fields on the product detail page in the store front for the customer to enter some information.

I have done much research and reading but all information seems to provide information and tutorials regarding the admin.

From what I can gather is I need to use Shopify Script Tags or App Blocks or theme extensions to add the custom input fields to the add to cart form on the product page. Which one should I be using?

Next I need this information to be added to the cart and included in the order the customer places. I may also need to influence the price based on the values of these fields.

Please provide some guidance / materials that could help me get started. Anything useful will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it for a custom app or an app that you to publish?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions, I'll try to give an idea on how you could proceed.

When adding a product to the cart you can add `properties` to the `lineItem`. `lineItem` is a line in the cart, its main attributes are `quantity`,`variantiId`, and `properties`  but there are many others.

Typically when you want to customize an item you add a property with the customisation.

Let's say I want to add a custom label to my phone case.

In your product page you have a form made like this

```
{% form 'product', product, id: "add-to-cart-form", novalidate: 'novalidate' %}

{% endform %}
```

Inside that form put an input like this

```
<input type="text" name="properties[custom_text]" value=""/>
```

If the input is filled by the customer with "My text", when the product is added to the cart, in your cart, the `lineItem` will be something like

`{... "variantId" : 123, "quantity" : 1, "properties" : {"custom_text" : "My Text"} }`

Note that properties are visible at checkout, unless the key starts with `_`, in that case only the shop can see them.

So your app would just need to add in the product form those input fields.

Regarding the price it's a bit more complicated, it's easier to add a product to the cart like "Customization" with a certain price.

Comment: The dynamic price in the cart is quite important, is there any information available for "customization with a price" ?

Comment: @MusaffarPatel An app cannot increase a price of a variant, but only apply a discount. Thus, either you create a new variant for a product with customzation (and you select it when a customization is selected) either you have a product to be added on the cart when the customization is applied (and you add it to the cart when a customizatoin is selected).

Comment: I don't think this approach would work.  I want the customer to supply numeric measurements and the app should be able to use these to calculate a dynamic price.  It wouldn't be possible to create variants therefore.  There must be a possible solution to this?

Comment: Maybe, I don't claim to know everything. One way is to have a variant with maximum possible price and put in the cart with the required price.